# How do i get certain data from my tree map

Tags: java, bluej

I have a java program that stores students, staff, and faculty in a directory.  I can get the program to print all the data in the directory, but I have been unable to print just the students.  Can anyone please give me some idea of which way to approach this.  this is driving me nuts.

Here is the code that is getting all the data from my directory:

```
 /**
 * Print the list using an iterator.
 */
private void printList()
{   
    // Retrieve data from the TreeMap
    Set directorySet = directory.entrySet();

    // Get an iterator
    Iterator iterator = directorySet.iterator();

    // Display elements
    System.out.println("Iterate through the TreeMap and print its contents \n");

    // Warning if TreeMap is empty. 
    if(directory.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("The directory is empty, nothing to show. Returning to main menu");

        MainMenu();
    } else 
    {
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry directory = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            System.out.print(directory.getKey() + ": ");
            System.out.println(directory.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Reached end of list");

        continueMenu();
    }
}
```

all I need to do is print all the names in the directory that are students.

here is the part of the code that is entering the student information.

```
 public void newPerson()
{
    // Input 
    String userInputTwo;

    // Scanner for user input.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("\n");

    // Add new user data.
    System.out.println("Enter the details of person you would like to add. \n");
    System.out.println("What is the last name?");
    lastname = userInput.next();
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("What is the first name?");
    firstname = userInput.next();
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("What is the Email?");
    Email = userInput.next();

    while(keepLoopingTypeOfPerson==true)
    {
        // Add new user data.
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Select the type of person: student, staff, faculty");
        String typeOfPerson = in.nextLine();
        switch(typeOfPerson)
        {
            case "student":
            String studentStatus = Students.GetStudentStatus();
            directory.put(lastname +" "+ firstname, " Email - " + Email 
                + ", Class Status - " + studentStatus);
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Person added \n");
            System.out.println("Add another person? y or n \n");
            userInputTwo = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

            if (userInputTwo.equals("y")) 
            {
                newPerson();
            } else if (userInputTwo.equals("n"))

            // return to menu
               keepLoopingNewPerson=true;
```

Comment: Instead of storing key as composed string, you should consider an key object with hash and eqauals methods, it will be easyer to do filtering on this. I would also advise to use 3 maps, for each type, as each type may have different attributes in the future.

Comment: How do you identify who is a student exactly? Is it through the Key or Value of your map? I think one issue here that needs to be looked at is, you have stored what seems to be 3 types. Name, email, and Student Status. However, you use the Name (last + first) as your Key, and then the value holds the Email and Class Status as a concatenated String. If you want to consider using multiple types, try looking at SQL Databases, or maybe another way to do so is save an array with Strings, and keep an order of how you want to set your data. String[0] = Name, String[1] = Email String[2] = Status.

Comment: I still cant get a clear understanding of your code

Comment: You could just use JSON Arrays and Objects to store this data